# Interesting behaviour of row, model row and view row - which one to use when?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, awt

It's a difficult one to explain, I will try and explain it in steps, running code side by side will help but looking at images should be enough to understand my question.

row and rowModel are consistent with data display and data model respectively but I cannot understand rowView at all. When will rowView be useful?

1)  Default view: Column B (1,2,3,4).

[image]

2)  Click to sort Column B header: Sort ascending (1,2,3,4). Always dataRow = modelRow = viewRow.

3)  Click to sort Column B header: Sort descending (4,3,2,1).

row 0 = rowModel 3 = rowView 3

row 1 = rowModel 2 = rowView 2

row 2 = rowModel 1 = rowView 1

row 3 = rowModel 0 = rowView 0

All as expected!

4)  Now click to sort Column C: Sorting ascending (figure below)

[image]

Column 0: value"4" -- row 0 = rowModel 3 = rowView 2 --- why rowView is 2?

Column 1: value"1" -- row 0 = rowModel 3 = rowView 2 --- 
why rowView is 2 and consistent behaviour in remaining cells as below?

Column 0: value"3" -- row 1 = rowModel 2 = rowView 3 --- why rowView is 3 ?

Column 1: value"3" -- row 1 = rowModel 2 = rowView 3 --- why rowView is 3 ?

Column 0: value"1" -- row 2 = rowModel 0 = rowView 1 --- why rowView is 1 ?

Column 1: value"4" -- row 2 = rowModel 0 = rowView 1 --- why rowView is 1 ?

Column 0: value"2" -- row 3 = rowModel 1 = rowView 0 --- why rowView is 0 ?

Column 1: value"5" -- row 3 = rowModel 1 = rowView 0 --- why rowView is 0 ?

Code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
import java.awt.*;

public class SortTableWithColors_ extends JFrame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SortTableWithColors_ frame = new SortTableWithColors_();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public SortTableWithColors_() {
        Object[] columnNames = {"B", "C"};
        Object[][] data = {{new Integer(1), new Integer(4)},
                {new Integer(2), new Integer(5)},
                {new Integer(3), new Integer(3)},
                {new Integer(4), new Integer(1)}};
        // table model
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);

        // set table model in Jtable
        JTable table = new JTable(model);
        table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
        getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(table));

        // Tell the table what to use to render our columns
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i).setCellRenderer(new NewRenderer());
        }
    }

    // Custom Renderer
    public class NewRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent
                (JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected,
                 boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            JLabel cell = (JLabel) super.getTableCellRendererComponent
                    (table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

            int rowModel = (int) table.convertRowIndexToModel(row);
            int colModel = (int) table.convertColumnIndexToModel(column);
            int rowView = (int) table.convertRowIndexToView(row);
            int colView = (int) table.convertColumnIndexToView(column);

            // set color
            cell.setBackground(new Color(0xFFFFFF));
            cell.setForeground(new Color(0x000000));

            //set selection colors
            if (isSelected) {
                cell.setBackground(new Color(0x4AC3FF));
                cell.setForeground(new Color(0x000000)); // AM
            }
            // Selective cell colouring based on value
            int val = (int) value;
            if (val == 1) {
                cell.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            }
            return cell;
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of the data in a `TableModel` is fixed.

The order of the data in a `JTable` can change because:

1. the `JTable` could be filtered or sorted, which means the row number of the `JTable` can be different than the row number in the `TableModel`
2. the user could reorder the columns, which means the column number of the `JTable` can be different than the column number in the `TableModel`.

There are two ways to access the data:

1. Using the JTable you can use: `table.getValueAt(...);`
2. Using the TableModel you can use `table.getModel().getValueAt(...);`

Lets say you have a table with 2 columns "FirstName, LastName" and you want to update the data to a database for the selected row so you need to get the values for the firstName and lastName.

When dealing with a `JTable` all the methods use row/column indexes relative to the table. So you might use code like:

```
String firstName = table.getValueAt(selectedRow, 0);
String lastName = table.getValueAt(selectedRow, 1);
```

This will work even if the table is sorted or filter since the selected row is relative to the table.

However, what if the user reorders the two columns. The code won't work because 
the hardcoded indexes will be wrong. So you have two options:

1) Get the data via the `JTable` but convert the column indexes:

```
String firstName = table.getValueAt(selectedRow, table.convertColumnIndexToView(0));
String lastName = table.getValueAt(selectedRow, table.convertColumnIndexToView(1));
```

So now both row/column indexes are relative to the table.

2) Get the data via the `TableModel`, but this time you need to convert the row index:

```
TableModel model = table.getModel();
int modelRow = table.convertRowIndexToModel( selectedRow );
String firstName = model.getValueAt(modelRow, 0);
String lastName = model.getValueAt(modelRow, 1);
```

I prefer this approach as only one conversion is needed.

The key point is you would never use all the conversion methods at the same time. You need to decide whether you want to access the data via the `JTable` or the `TableModel` and then do the appropriate conversion.

Comment: Thanks for excellent explanation. I prefer to use data via Jtable, as it during sorting and filtering operations row indexes are the least to be worried about, especially when defining cell renderer.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the renderer's `row` and `column` values are *view* coordinates, so only two of your conversions are meaningful:

```
int rowModel = (int) table.convertRowIndexToModel(row);
int colModel = (int) table.convertColumnIndexToModel(column);
//int rowView = (int) table.convertRowIndexToView(row);
//int colView = (int) table.convertColumnIndexToView(column);
```

Add a line to display model coordinates in parentheses for the selected row to see the effect. When unsorted, the model and view indices are the same:

```
if (isSelected) {
    …
    System.out.println(row + " (" + rowModel + ") " + column + " (" + colModel +")");
}
```

When to be especially vigilant:

- Because the user can change column order by dragging, convert when accessing the model as shown for [tooltips](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#celltooltip).
- Because the user can change row order by sorting, convert when accessing the model in a `TableCellRenderer`, `TableCellEditor` or `ListSelectionListener` as shown [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting).